# How to Rotate an image over another with fixed position ionic1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have to **rotate an image** on touch on a fixed axis. Currently I am able to set the image to a fixed position with certain angle. But when i am trying to rotate it with some other deg. then the position of image gets changed.

I have set the  transform-origin: 0 0; Since my image is covering more area. the rotation is not working as i want.
[My screen shot goes here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5TSd.png)

I have an axis with an arrow which needs to rotate on the X-Y Axis image at its center.

Any suggestions will be very helpful.

Comment: Anyone who can help me with this...?

Comment: I think nobody knows the answer